# run_interrupt_driven_hooks still waiting after 60 seconds for xpt_config

Tags: freebsd

I have downloaded the [FreeBSD 9.0](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/i386/ISO-IMAGES/9.0/FreeBSD-9.0-RELEASE-i386-dvd1.iso) for i836 but during boot/installation I get the following message:

```
run_interrupt_driven_hooks: still waiting after 60 seconds for xpt_config
```

I waited for 10 minutes and nothing changed. I have no idea how to fix this. 
I tried to run it on: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5450 @ 1.66GHz,2GB RAM.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how I can correct it?

Comment: Have you found any solution? This is still a problem in FreeBSD 10.2.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski: No, I never managed to it work on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Which hardware are you using? Does it include IEEE1394 aka firewire?

I ask because there are known problems with some boards with have firewire enabled.

Note that XPT is not just firewire specific though. It is a driver provides a way for userland applications to issue certain CAM CCBs (SCSI commands) to the kernel. So it could be other stuff. But disabling firewire in the BIOS and then trying to boot is an easy test.

[Edit] Added link to open PR:  http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=136327

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know if it include IEEE1394. How do I see about firewire of my computer? and how to disable the firewire?

Comment: Depending on your hardware the easiest way might be go into the BIOS and look for firewire. Alternative are reading the motherboard manual or looking though dmesg.

Comment: I have looked for "firewire" in BIOS,but not found anything.. the `lspci` command can help you to point me a way?

Comment: I have tried this too as @Jonh mentioned: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4098/how-to-disable-firewire-in-openbsd-linux-to-prevent-attacks-through-firewire

Comment: All this is assuming that it the hardware has firewire. There might be another problem.  FW seems to be the most common source of there errors (or at least the ones I have seen most).

Answer (score 0):

Remove your PCI controllers and boot into FreeBSD OS and make the following entry in the `/boot/loader.conf` file

```
hw.pci.enable_msix=0
hw.pci.enable_msi=0
```

and try to boot with PCI controller.

Comment: Where is this file? do I need to compile the kernel by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't change anything in my BIOS I came up with a solution like this:

Append

```
hint.ata.0.disabled="1"
hint.ata.1.disabled="1"
```

to the `/boot/device.hints` file.

I don't know why it is working however. [Here is my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1055316/why-does-disabling-ata-fixes-run-interrupt-driven-hooks-still-waiting-after-60) where I am trying to clarify it.